# How to get size in KB of batch of PreparedStatements prior to execution?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I need to know the size of the jdbc batch prior to execution. The idea is to use network throttling using [token bucket approach](https://github.com/bbeck/token-bucket).  Basically, I need to know how much my batch will consume from the basket. This runs as JUnit test.

As an alternative, Maybe there are libraries to act as proxies that can return the size post factum?

Comment: There is nothing like that in JDBC itself, which database and driver are you using?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7

Comment: As far as I am aware, MySQL Connector/J has nothing like this.